# Unable to get input data value in console in NestJS

Tags: node.js, nestjs

I am making an post request where I am posting phone number via Postman request.In Postman I have set `Content-Type:application/json` but I am getting empty obbject **{}** in console.Below is my Postman screenshot of setting header and posting value.

[image]

[image]
Below is my code:

**subscriber.controller.ts**

```
@Controller()
export class SubscribeController {
constructor(private subscribeService:SubscribeService){}
  
    @Post('location')
    async getLocation(@Body() phoneNumber:String){
   
    const loc = await this.subscribeService.getLocation(phoneNumber);
    return loc; 
   }
}
```

**subscriber.service.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class SubscribeService {
constructor(private httpService: HttpService){}

      async getLocation(phoneNumber:String){
   
      return console.log(phoneNumber);
    }
}
```

Someone let me know why its showing empty object in console.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to pass a body `object` as a `string` value, update your `@Body` decorator with `JSON key` to specify **phoneNumber** data field:

```js
  @Post('location')
  async getLocation(@Body('phoneNumber') thisIsJustTheVariableName: string) {
    console.log(thisIsJustTheVariableName); // will extract phoneNumber from your body object
  }
```

---

The better way of handling Request Body is to determine some `dto` objects for your example:

```js
  class SubscriberDto {
    phoneNumber: string;
    // may be some additional fields
  }

  @Post('location')
  async getLocation(@Body() sub: SubscriberDto) {
    console.log(sub.phoneNumber); // will extract phoneNumber from your body object
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Update: `return console.log(phoneNumber);` in your service returns undefined, which you return in controller. If I'm not mistaken by default nest will change it to empty object in such case.
One more bug: `@Body() phoneNumber:String` in controller is incorrect, as you send JSON object.

Outdated: You've set `x-www-form-urlencoded` type for body on screen 2. Use `raw` type and provide correct JSON

Comment: Hey I have tried it but did not worked I am getting empty object.

Comment: Please take a look I have updated my 2 screenshot as well as controller and service code.

Answer (score 0):

It is too late to answer, but this can someone who facing same issue.

to recieve fields in form data you can use like this

```
@Post('location')
    async getLocation(@Body() phoneNumber:String){
    @UseInterceptors(NoFilesInterceptor()) // NoFilesInterceptor will get all form data
    const loc = await this.subscribeService.getLocation(phoneNumber);
    return loc; 
   }
```

check [this](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/file-upload#no-files) for reference.